# Not able to reproduce test predictions with gbm

Tags: r, seed, gbm

I am using `gbm` to build a predictive regression model. I have train and test sets (pre-defined and **NOT** randomly chosen). Following is an overview of the code.

I have around 600 rows in train data and 150 rows in test data. I know they are very less but still.

```
train <- ....
test <- ....

set.seed(123)
model <- gbm(target ~., data = train,
                distribution = "gaussian",
                n.trees = 4000,
                interaction.depth = 2,
                n.minobsinnode = 5,
                shrinkage = 0.01,
                bag.fraction = 1,
                train.fraction = .95,
                verbose = TRUE
            )

best_iter <- gbm.perf(model)

set.seed(123)
predictions <- predict(model, newdata = test, n.trees = best_iter)

set.seed(123)
predictions <- predict(model, newdata = train, n.trees = best_iter)
```

Somehow, when I run the gbm model again and again with exactly the same parameters I am ***not able to reproduce*** predictions on the test set. But at the same time I am always able to reproduce predictions on train set. I am setting seed also before building model and making predictions. Can someone please help me with figuring out what's happening? Please note, train and test data always remain same, I don't change them at all in every run.

Comment: Difficult to answer without data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure out the problem? I am doing the exact same model approach as you and the only difference in our code that I can see is your call to predict. You could try removing the dependent variable from the newdata for each of train and test. Also, set n.trees directly, not sure what you are getting the way you have it currently. And save the predictions to two separate objects.

```
PredEst <- predict(model, newdata = train[-which(names(train) %in% as.character("target"))], n.trees = 4000)

PredVal <- predict(model, newdata = test[-which(names(test) %in% as.character("target"))], n.trees = 4000)
```